# Programmatically execute Chrome's "Add to Home Screen" shortcut from another app

Tags: android, google-chrome

It seems to run Chrome full screen on Android, you need to open Chrome, go to the website, then select 'Add to Home Screen' from the Chrome menu. That creates a shortcut to the link and puts it on the home screen. If the website has the proper meta mobile tags, it then runs full screen from that shortcut.

I would like to execute that shortcut from my program. I know about intents and the like, but this is different because it's a specially created Chrome link.

How could I execute this desktop shortcut programmatically from within a program?

Comment: You seem to be confused between an IDE (Android Studio), an operating system (Android), and a program that you might write for Android using Android Studio. Are you really asking "how can my Android app execute a home screen shortcut?". If so, is your app the home screen, or is it some other app? That sort of confusion is probably why this question was closed.

Comment: @CommonsWare According to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400966/my-programming-qustion-on-hold they are asking how an app can execute a home screen short cut.

Comment: Sry for the confusion. Yes I would like my app, written in Android Studio, to programmatically start/execute/launch the chrome created link which would be on the home screen/desktop of the android tablet.